# Django Based Site Not Responding

Tags: django, linux, web-services, apache, networking

I hope this hasnt been asked before, am new to linux programing. We have a site built on django running on an linux server, however, recently our network setup was reset, though all IP adresses and settings remained the same, the thing is that the site cannot be accessed now even though the server still uses the same ip address as before, it gives this error "

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.66 Port 80"

If anyone has an idea of whats going on, the help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `192.168.1.66` is an address reserved for internal addresses. I assume that your site is on an Intranet? Because if you are getting that through a public IP, you have a problem...

Comment: what error do you get in the apache logs?